# iTunes Reciept Validation - in_app empty

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

During the server side validation of iTunes receipt we are encountering some receipt for which we are getting empty "in_app" purchases. An empty in_app array indicates that StoreKit has not recorded any transactions for that user yet. Why this is happening and do we have any solution for handling this kind of in_app empty receipts.

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "environment": "Production",
  "receipt": {
    "receipt_type": "Production",
    "adam_id": *******,
    "app_item_id": *******,
    "bundle_id": "com.***************",
    "application_version": "0",
    "download_id": 85015170192768,
    "version_external_identifier": 816491596,
    "receipt_creation_date": "2016-03-10 16:29:03 Etc/GMT",
    "receipt_creation_date_ms": "1457627343000",
    "receipt_creation_date_pst": "2016-03-10 08:29:03 America/Los_Angeles",
    "request_date": "2016-03-11 05:24:19 Etc/GMT",
    "request_date_ms": "1457673859599",
    "request_date_pst": "2016-03-10 21:24:19 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_purchase_date": "2015-12-27 15:37:38 Etc/GMT",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1451230658000",
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2015-12-27 07:37:38 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_application_version": "1",
    "in_app": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An empty in_app array indicates that StoreKit has not recorded any transactions for that user yet. It may be that the application receipt has not yet been updated. When this happens, your app can inform the user that the receipt does not appear current and ask whether to refresh it. Upon user agreement, your app should use the SKReceiptRefreshRequest class to update the receipt. At this point, if StoreKit has recorded a purchase for the user, your app receipt will show it in in_app. See [Refreshing the App Receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW2) for more information on how to update a receipt.

For more information check out : [My app validates its receipt with the App Store via paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: after a successful purchase. However, the returned receipt contains an empty in_app array rather than the expected products.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-RECEIPT-MY_APP_VALIDATES_ITS_RECEIPT_WITH_THE_APP_STORE_VIA_PAYMENTQUEUE_UPDATEDTRANSACTIONS__AFTER_A_SUCCESSFUL_PURCHASE__HOWEVER__THE_RETURNED_RECEIPT_CONTAINS_AN_EMPTY_IN_APP_ARRAY_RATHER_THAN_THE_EXPECTED_PRODUCTS_)